# height:auto after div position

Tags: css

There is a frame consisting of three sections from top to bottom.
Bottom covering section 3 relative area

[image]

in
1 part absolute certain height 100px
2 sections height of certain non-auto
In section 3 from 2 after auto replace the div I want to place the absolute location data from the two auto does not mean anything
3 How do you think should be part div css?

Answer (score 0):

Friendly speaking, your question is not completely clear... As far as I understand from the picture, you want to put your red `div` under 2 absolutely positioned `divs` (green and yellow).

You can absolutely position your red `div` inside yellow `div` and make it top value more than 100%, like so:

```
.red-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Or if you know the height of yellow and green `divs` together, you can do just

```
.red-div {
    margin-top: (sum of your yellow and green heights and there margins) px;
}
```